# Search in xpath

Tags: java, xpath

Suppose this is the xml:

```
<lib>
<books type="paperback" name="A" />
<books type="pdf" name="B" />
<books type="hardbound" name="A" />
</lib>
```

What will be the xpath code to search for book of type="paperback" and name="A"? TIA.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
   import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class demo {

  public static void main(String[] args) 
   throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, 
          IOException, XPathExpressionException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = 
    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("xml.xml");
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
       // XPath Query for showing all nodes value
    String version="fl1.0";
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//books/type[@input="paperback"]/text()");

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
     System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And `xpath.compile("//books/type[@input="paperback"]/text()")` is no valid Java, either.

Comment: Sad but true: Java is the language where frameworks rely most heavily on XML but that ist most poorly equiped to handle XML.

Comment: Yes, although you could add `<?xml version="1.0"?>`.

Comment: Okay.That was omitted knowingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/lib/books[@type='paperback' and @name='A']
```

Have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp) if you're struggling with xpath syntax, it has a few nice examples.

Also, if you just need help with XML in general and related technologies, have a look at the guide [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_whatis.asp)

Comment: @Fiona: I went through the code, but still a bit confused. If I need to search for "paperback" and retrieve corresponding name, can u tell me the code for the same?

Comment: /lib/books[@type='paperback']/@name

Comment: One more, 
Since the type attribute differs in every tag in the above XML. Can we hold the value of Type in a String variable and substitute it in the xpath search variable?

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I understand your question, but you can definitely construct the xpath expression in Java and concatenate in a string variable, yes.

Comment: I want to create a String variable "type" and set it with the type of book(paperback, pdf et al) and use the variable in the xpath search.
String TYPE="pdf";
 /lib/books[@type='*insert TYPE here']/@name.
Would this be correct?

Comment: Yeah, so you could do 
String type="pdf"; and then String xpath = "/lib/books[@type='" + type + "']/@name";

Answer (score 0):

Right now you seem to search for something like `<book><type input="paperback"/></book>` which clearly is wrong. Your xpath expression should probably be something like //books[@type="paperback" and @name="A"]/text()

Comment: Since the `books` elements have no conente, `text()` will give you nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are good...I wanted to contribute a resource.  The best xpath tutorial I've seen is [here](http://www.zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html#Pages~List_of_XPaths).